# ArrayIndexOutOfBound in a task servlet on app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i'm having a problem in a task servlet on app engine.
**Sometimes** i receive a arraylist indexoutofbound exception.
The log print that i have added correctly 3 string (subdomain) to a arraylist, but whe i try to access with:

```
stringUser.add(entry.getTitle().getPlainText()+"@"+listaDeiSottodomini.get(o));
```

I receive:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 9, Size: 4
```

or

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

or

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
```

How is it possible? Here is my code

```
String [] sottodomini=subdomains.split(",");

           listaDeiSottodomini.add(consumerKey);
           if(sottodomini.length>0 ){
           for(int y=0;y<sottodomini.length;y++){
               if(!sottodomini[y].equals("")){
                   log.info("Aggiungo "+sottodomini[y]+" alla lista dei sottodomini abilitati al contact sharing");
               listaDeiSottodomini.add(sottodomini[y]);  
               }
           }
           }
        log.info("ArrayList value "+listaDeiSottodomini);
        try {
            UserService myService = new UserService("My Application");
            myService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, signer);

            for(int o=0;o<listaDeiSottodomini.size();o++){
            URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/"+listaDeiSottodomini.get(o)+"/user/2.0");
            while (metafeedUrl != null) {
                UserFeed resultFeed;

                resultFeed = myService.getFeed(metafeedUrl, UserFeed.class);

                entries.addAll(resultFeed.getEntries());


                for(int i=0; i<resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
                    UserEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);


                    if(!entry.getLogin().getSuspended()){
                    stringUser.add(entry.getTitle().getPlainText()+"@"+listaDeiSottodomini.get(o));
                    }else{
                        log.warning("L'utente "+entry.getTitle().getPlainText()+"@"+listaDeiSottodomini.get(o)+" è in stato sospeso e quindi non è stato considerato nella procedura di condivisione"); 

                    }
                    }
                // Check for next page
                Link nextLink = resultFeed.getNextLink();
                if (nextLink == null) {
                    metafeedUrl = null;
                } else {
                    metafeedUrl = new URL(nextLink.getHref());
                }
            }
            }

        } catch (AppsForYourDomainException e) {
            log.warning("Errore di AppsForYourDomainException nel recupero degli utenti con messaggio "+e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            log.warning("Errore di ServiceException nel recupero degli utenti con messaggio "+e.getMessage().toString());
        } catch (OAuthException e) {
            log.warning("Errore di OAuthException nel recupero degli utenti con messaggio "+e.getMessage().toString());

        }


}
```

Comment: You should publish the entire stacktrace, AND indicate which line is the one indicated in it

Comment: Or don't publish it.  Believe the stack trace.  It tells you the line number and the file at which the exception was thrown.  Put your incorrect assumptions aside that say your code is correct, navigate to that line in a debugger, and figure out how the actual state of that array conflicts with your assumptions.